# What is OPENMP_DIRECTIVE_EXT and how to declare a new one?

Tags: openmp, llvm, llvm-clang

The [freecompilercamp.org](http://freecompilercamp.org/clang-llvm-landing/) has a very good tutorial about defining OpenMP Directives.
However, apart from this I was unable to find any good resource on how to add new directives,
clauses etc for OpenMP in llvm.

Moreover, I am interested in knowing more about what OPENMP_DIRECTIVE_EXT is and how to declare a new one? Any guide about this or how the User defined Reduction is implemented would be helpful. Even a link to the patchset or pull request that added this functionality would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Citing the [openMP spec](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpch2.html#x30-290002) -

> Compilers can therefore ignore OpenMP directives and conditionally compiled code if support of the OpenMP API is not provided or enabled. A compliant implementation must provide an option or interface that ensures that underlying support of all OpenMP directives and OpenMP conditional compilation mechanisms is enabled. In the remainder of this document, the phrase OpenMP compilation is used to mean a compilation with these OpenMP features enabled.

In other words, the directives are a programming tool to allow compilers to compile code under it if an existing implementation for such a directive exists and otherwise falls back to compiling the code as normal for a cpu. I also found this [IBM page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_12.1.0/com.ibm.xlc121.aix.doc/proguide/cuppovrv2.html) which explains the pragmas a bit further.

I didn't really find any other tutorial than the one you mention. You should probably look at the clang tutorials in that site. I think the OpenMP directives are implemented as a clang frontend parser. You need to parse the structured code inside the directive and add a new AST node. This will be compiled to LLVM IR and passed to LLVM where you can do more transformations to the IR.